# On scroll move item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a complete beginner in JS and front-end. I am working on a website and I have an image in this div with the id `main-image`.

When the user scrolls down the image I want it to go left slowly and then delete the image.

```js
var x = 0;
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("main-image");

  setInterval(function() {
    if (x <= screenWidth) {
      x++;
      box.style.left = x + "px";
    } else {
      box.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
.site-header {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2159065/pexels-photo-2159065.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=627&w=1200");
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#main-image {
  position: marker;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid site-header" id="main-image">
  <div class="image-on-text-container bg-secondary">
    <span class="site-brand"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote this script for this, but it's moving badly. I want it to move slower, and maybe with some effect, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you provide the code for that image, rather than just the `<div>` it's in?

Comment: yes i will edit the question i put the url in css

Comment: The interval is measured in milliseconds. You put 10 which is 1/100th of a second. Try a bigger number.

Comment: @chiliNUT i try that but my screen size getting bigger and bigger in width till it compeletly going out of screen

Comment: `position: marker;` is your invention? Otherwise seems like an invalid value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example

Comment: `setInterval` inside a `"scroll"` event is really bad. Think again about it, On every scroll tick you're assigning heavy intervals of 10ms - on top of existing ones

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no i just use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position

Comment: @PouryaMohamadi nope, you explicitly use `position: marker;` which has nothing to do with that you linked. Read the Docs I posted above.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can u please give me  a link then i can read more about this to fix this scrolling iam totaly begginer in js

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i change the position to  relative its woks fine but i still need help to fix the scroll

Comment: Why do you need the `box.style.display = "none";` ? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan when i move the photo from screen my screen getting bigger and bigger in width so i deside to use box.style.display = "none";

Comment: @PouryaMohamadi that's not necessary if you set `overflow-x: hidden;` to a parent element. Currently you're getting x scrollbars which is also bad.

Comment: Also, try to add a timing to your transition: `transition: 0.3s ease-out;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the `y` delta instead and animate transition over a timing value of i.e: `0.Ns` and translate the x coordinate over that delta value multiplied by 100 to get the percentage value. Don't forget to add `overflow: hidden;` to a parent element

```js
const elBox = document.querySelector(".image-on-text-container");

const moveImage = () => {
  const rect = elBox.getBoundingClientRect();
  const yDelta = -rect.top / rect.height;
  const x = Math.max(0, yDelta); // prevent negative value (move only to left)
  elBox.style.translate = `${x * 100}% 0`;
};

addEventListener("scroll", moveImage); // Do on scroll
moveImage(); // and on init
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.site-header {
  overflow: hidden; /* Remove scrollbars */
}

.image-on-text-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2159065/pexels-photo-2159065.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=627&w=1200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid site-header" id="main-image">
  <div class="image-on-text-container bg-secondary">
    <span class="site-brand"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<p style="height: 100vh;">Scroll back up.....</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animating elements through their position values (e.g. left) has its drawbacks and does not render as smoothly as translates do, since it cannot be purely calculated by the gpu. See a more detailed explanation [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

Here is an example with transform: translatex() set as a global CSS variable.

```js
const styleRoot = document.querySelector(':root');
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
let lastScrollTop = 0;
const factor = 1;

// Sets a global css Variable var(--boxTranslate)
function setTranslate(xValue) {
 styleRoot.style.setProperty('--boxTranslate', `translateX(-${xValue * factor}px)`);
}

// Checks if element is on screen
function isVisible(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}

function onScroll(scrollEvent) {
  const box = document.getElementById('box')
  
  if (!box) {
    return
  } else if (!isVisible(box)) {
    box.remove();
  }
  
  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
    // Scrolling down
    setTranslate(scrollTop)
  }
}

window.onscroll = onScroll;
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 5000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: teal;
  transition: all 125ms ease-out;
  transform: var(--boxTranslate);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  I go left as you scroll and get removed when I'm out of sight
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

change these two blocks:

```
     #main-image {
        position: marker;
        left: 0;
        transition: all ease-out 3s;
     }
```

and this:

```
     window.onscroll = function () {
        var box = document.getElementById("main-image")
        if (x == 0) {
           x = screenWidth
           box.style.left = x + "px"
        }
     }
```

Comment: use addEventListener instead of overriding on* handlers.

Comment: Also, use rather transform / translate, instead of non-GPU accelerable properties like `left`.

Comment: What is `position: marker;` ?